# @angular-cli ng serve livereload doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am new on Angular2 and @angular-cli. I am download @angular-cli and I try to use it with livereload but doesn't work. I tried to downgrade at version 1.4.2 but still not working.

I have this failure:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/home/cesar/Repositorios/proyectoAlbum/client-albums/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:9514:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (/home/cesar/Repositorios/proyectoAlbum/client-albums/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:63770:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (/home/cesar/Repositorios/proyectoAlbum/client-albums/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:380:33)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/home/cesar/Repositorios/proyectoAlbum/client-albums/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:9514:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (/home/cesar/Repositorios/proyectoAlbum/client-albums/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:63770:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (/home/cesar/Repositorios/proyectoAlbum/client-albums/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:380:33)
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

This is my version of @angular-cli and node

```
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.10.2
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 4.0.1
@angular/compiler: 4.0.1
@angular/core: 4.0.1
@angular/forms: 4.0.1
@angular/http: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.1
@angular/router: 4.0.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.1
```

Regards!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not upgrade correctly. The NGtools binding is not set correctly.

Follow these steps : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

---

Also :

> require Node 6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.

You can download the latest version here : https://nodejs.org/en/.
It is working correctly for me.